# Finding all groups in a split string

Tags: c#, string, linq

**Note** the title doesn't exactly reflect what I need to do but I can't find correct words for that since my English is not perfect. If anyone want to correct it, feel free.

---

Given a string containing groups (separated by n points) I would like to get all values with: group[0]; group[0].group[1]; group[0].group[1]..group[n].

Example: input: `Tr.WH.Eu6.ISC` would give:

- Tr
- Tr.WH
- Tr.WH.Eu6
- Tr.WH.Eu6.ISC

For now I have this code:

```
string input = "Tr.WH.Eu6.ISC";
string[] splitStrings = input.Split('.');
List<string> subs = new List<string> { "" };
for (int i = 0; i < splitStrings.Count(); i++)
{
    subs.Add(subs.Last() + "." + splitStrings[i]);
}
subs.Remove("");
```

Which I found ugly and doesn't fully work as it outputs:

- .Tr
- .Tr.WH
- .Tr.WH.Eu6
- .Tr.WH.Eu6.ISC

How can I make it works (preferably with Linq) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
string input = "Tr.WH.Eu6.ISC";
string[] groups = input.Split('.');
string[] output = groups.Select((x, idx) => string.Join(".", groups.Take(idx + 1)))
                        .ToArray();
```

For each group, where idx is the index of the group, take (idx + 1) entries from the groups collection and join them with the "." delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know a way to do this fully in `Linq`, but you can clean up the code a bit by using `String.Join` and `.Take` (this comes from Linq).

```
string input = "Tr.WH.Eu6.ISC";
string[] splitStrings = input.Split('.');
List<string> subs = new List<string>();
for (int i = 1; i <= splitStrings.Count(); i++)
{
    subs.Add(String.Join(".", splitStrings.Take(i).ToArray()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var v = str.Split('.');
            for(int i=0;i<v.Count();i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(".", v.Take(i+1)));
        }
```

We still go with the `Split` method, and then use `Join` and `Take` in a loop to show increasing number of segments each time.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/JOK13531)

Another way:

```
var v = str.Split('.');
Enumerable.Range(1,v.Count()).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(string.Join(".", v.Take(x))));
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/RMY80938)

Answer (score 0):

Without LINQ. Splitting string into array and then joining - it is not efficient code by memory.

```
static IEnumerable<string> SplitIntoGroups(string s, char delimiter)
{
    for (int findPos = 0, delimPos = 0; 
            (delimPos = s.IndexOf(delimiter, findPos)) != -1; 
            findPos = delimPos + 1)
    {
        yield return s.Substring(0, delimPos);
    }

    yield return s;
}
```